# remove all rows with the values in all column similar with another pyspark dataframe

Tags: python, dataframe, pyspark

For example, if i have 2 pyspark dataframe with 100++ columns.
I wish to compare dataframe A, with Dataframe B and check whether is there row with similar values based on all 100++columns. If yes, then remove the rows.

I do not have a code because I do not know how to begin. please help.
I am wondering whether could I use outer join between two dataframes.

Comment: is there anyone who know how we could do it.

Comment: `left anti` join would be useful. see [this blog](https://towardsdatascience.com/why-is-nobody-talking-about-sql-anti-joins-f970a5f6cb54) for examples and their understanding

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `left_anti` join removes matching rows from the left table, and is well suited for your use case. Here's an example.

```py
data1_sdf.show()

# +---+---+---+---+
# | c1| c2| c3| c4|
# +---+---+---+---+
# |  1|  2|  3|  4|
# |  1|  2|  3|  4|
# |  3|  2|  1|  4|
# +---+---+---+---+

data2_sdf.show()

# +---+---+---+---+
# | c1| c2| c3| c4|
# +---+---+---+---+
# |  1|  2|  3|  4|
# |  5|  7|  3|  4|
# +---+---+---+---+

# left anti join to remove matching rows from data1_sdf
data1_sdf. \
    withColumn('allcol_concat', func.concat_ws('_', *data1_sdf.columns)). \
    join(data2_sdf.withColumn('allcol_concat', func.concat_ws('_', *data2_sdf.columns)).
         select('allcol_concat'),
         'allcol_concat',
         'leftanti'
         ). \
    show()

# +-------------+---+---+---+---+
# |allcol_concat| c1| c2| c3| c4|
# +-------------+---+---+---+---+
# |      3_2_1_4|  3|  2|  1|  4|
# +-------------+---+---+---+---+
```